# How to parse parameters from a single page application URL?

Tags: javascript, url, asp.net-mvc-2

My URL is this,

```
http://localhost:1871/Home/Index#/user/20
```

How do I extract 20 from this url into a variable using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do

```
var parts = document.location.pathname.split('/');
var number = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

`number` is your required variable. If "/user/20" is an anchor, then just replace `pathname` with `hash`.

Comment: This doesn't work (in Chrome at least). number would be the string 'Index'.

Comment: document.location.pathname doesn't include the hash, so for the URL given, document.location.pathname is '/Home/Index'. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties.

Comment: To test it do `"/Home/Index#/user/20".split('/')` instead and try. That will be `document.location.pathname` for him.

Comment: document.location.pathname isn't "/Home/Index#/user/20", it's just "/Home/Index".

Answer (score 3):

One liner: `var id = window.location.hash.split('/').pop();`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
parts = window.location.hash.substr(2).split('/');
id = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can do that.

1) Add to your project [jQuery URL Parser Plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)

2) Get your parameter

```
$.url('http://localhost:1871/Home/Index#/user/20').fsegment(1); // returns 'user'
$.url('http://localhost:1871/Home/Index#/user/20').fsegment(2); // returns '20'
```

I think it's very elegant/easy/understandable